# Create a postgres view and cast nullalble field to not-null

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have a polymorphic table, like so:

| id (Uuid, not null) | name (Text, nullable) | other_property (Bool, not null) |

and a check constraint like this:

```
other_property OR name IS NOT NULL
```

The idea behind this being that there are two "types" of objects in this table, one with a name and one without - and the reason I'm doing *that* is because I don't want to duplicate the relationship tables (i.e. "one_to_many_table_with_name", "one_to_many_table_without_name").

When creating a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW with_name as 
    SELECT id, name FROM my_table WHERE other_property = False;
```

because the root table's `name` field is nullable, the view's `name` field is also nullable, even though I know it can't be null due to the check constraint.

is there a way to force postgres to make the column as NOT NULL?

Comment: What difference does it make if the column is considered `NULL`able or not?

Comment: There is no need for that. NOT NULL constraints apply when inserting or updating a row in a table. Entered data will be restricted by the table constraints, even if the modifications are done by a view.